# Fixed number of template arguments from a variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

```
template <template <typename> class F> struct call_me {};
template <typename T> struct maybe;
template <typename... T> struct more;

int main()
{
  call_me<maybe> a; // ok
  call_me<more> b;  // error
}
```

I understand why `call_me<more>` fails. But I want to make it work.

Is there a workaround that doesn't involve changing `call_me` (or add an specialization to it)?

Comment: Since you can't modify call_me, you can create an alias template for more that takes a single parameter, and pass that to call_me.

Comment: That's imo ugly, but it would work. Would it be possible to write a generic wrapper for this? (Why isn't that an answer btw?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <template <typename> class F> struct call_me {};
template <typename T> struct maybe;
template <typename... T> struct more;
template <template <class...> class F> struct just_one {
  template <class A> using tmpl = F<A>;
};

int main()
{
  call_me<maybe> a; 
  call_me<just_one<more>::tmpl> b;  
}
```

Not exactly equivalent, but maybe close enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T> using onemore = more<T>;

int main()
{
    call_me<onemore> b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap `more`:

```
template <template <typename...> class Tmpl>
struct variwrap
{
    template <typename> struct Dummy
    {
        template <typename ...Brgs>
        struct rebind
        {
            typedef Tmpl<Brgs...> other;
        };
    };
};
```

Now you can say `call_me<variwrap<more>::Dummy>`, and the consumer can use `F::rebind<Args...>::other` to recover `more<Args...>`. Of course `call_me` has no way of knowing that `F` *has* the `rebind` member, so you'll need to add a specialization.

Yuck.